# "Duplicate symbol" error when using ghc-mod as a library

Tags: haskell, compilation, ghc, yesod, ghci

I'm trying to use the ghc-mod library to typecheck a haskell program from within another program. When I do so, I get the following error:

```
 GHCi runtime linker: fatal error: I found a duplicate definition for symbol
  __stginit_hsloggerzm1zi2zi3_SystemziLog
whilst processing object file
  /home/joey/stuff/workspace/myproject/.cabal-sandbox/lib/x86_64-linux-ghc-7.6.3/hslogger-1.2.3/libHShslogger-1.2.3.a
This could be caused by:
  * Loading two different object files which export the same symbol
  * Specifying the same object file twice on the GHCi command line
  * An incorrect `package.conf' entry, causing some object to be
    loaded twice.
GHCi cannot safely continue in this situation.  Exiting now.  Sorry.

Exit code: ExitFailure 1
```

I have no idea what hslogger is, as it isn't a dependency in my cabal file. The error happens even when the input file is just `x=3`, so it's not any weird import in the file being checked.

Does anyone know what might be causing this? I'm calling ghc-mod from within a thread in yesod, might this be causing problems? Is ghc-mod known to be non-threadsafe?

Comment: Does the input file have any import statements?

Comment: Nope, I get the same error on an input file with no imports.

Comment: I suppose you use `findCradle`? Do you get the error also when you explicitly set the `cradleCabalDir` and `cradleCabalFile` to `Nothing`